# How do I have start different services based on RAILS environment in docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose

```
I would like to start service-A, service-B, service-C if RAILS_ENV is development
I would like to start service-A, service-B, service-D if RAILS_ENV is staging
I would like to start service-A, service-B, service-E if RAILS_ENV is production
```

How should I override intelligently in docker-compose.yaml file.

```
service-C, service-D, service-E are not variants of the same service, but could be completely different containers as well
```

Comment: Are `service-C`, `service-D` and `service-E` different configs for the same service, or are completely different ones? Please give more context to avoid X-Y problem

Comment: service-C, service-D, service-E are not variants of the same service, but could be completely different containers as well

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to call docker-compose from a script.

If your docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
service-A:
    # Your service definition

service-B:
    # Your service definition
    depends_on:
        - service-A

service-C:
    # Your service definition
    depends_on:
        - service-B

service-D:
    # Your service definition
    depends_on:
        - service-B

service-E:
    # Your service definition
    depends_on:
        - service-B
```

Then, instead of calling `docker-compose up`, call a script that performs the conditional logic by checking environment variable RAILS_ENV, like this:

```sh
./start-services.sh
```

Where the script definition looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $RAILS_ENV== "development" ]
  then
  docker-compose up service-C
elif [ $TESTVAR == "staging" ]
  then
  docker-compose up service-D
elif [ $TESTVAR == "production" ]
  then
  docker-compose up service-E
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Of course, this implementation is a but unix-dependent, but I think it can be generalized to any operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Docker-compose has [overrides](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case), you can have:

- shared base config in `docker-compose.yml` with service-A and service-B
- service-C config in `docker-compose.override.yml` for development (docker compose should pick up this one by default)
- service-E config in `docker-compose.production.yml`, and run like

  ```sh
  docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml up -d
  ```
- similarly for service-E in `docker-compose.staging.yml`